# Using Meta to call attention to a post

Tags: discussion, meta

Do we -- can we -- use Meta to call attention to posts, not for moderation purposes, but for giving a shoutout to posts that might otherwise be overlooked?

*Scenario #1*

You post an answer to an old question that already has many answers. Left to itself, it's unlikely to be seen, since it's near the end of the set of answers, some of which have fairly high scores; readers would be justified in focusing on those and ignoring others. Clearly, having posted it, you find value in it. Could Meta be used to call attention to it?

*Scenario #2*

You came across a post you found quite extraordinary and placed a bounty on it. That did call some attention, but would/should a post on Meta extolling the post's virtues have been an additional means to that end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The straightforward answer is no, that isn't what meta is for, your Scenario #1 is a big no-no, and for Scenario #2 you can always post another bounty once that one is complete.

That said:

Various sites have used a meta post to coordinate activities such as week long events to reward folks who hunt down and answer unanswered questions, or spur activity in specific tags. These are different to your two scenarios, though.